# Use of template<typename>

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Say I have code like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename>
void printnum(int i) {

    std::cout<<"in int method:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< i<<std::endl;
}

template<typename>
void printnum(char i) {

    std::cout<<"in char method:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<(int)i<<std::endl;
}

int main() {

    printnum<int>(2);
    printnum<char>(3);
}
```

output:

```
in int method:
2
in int method:
3
```

My intention for this test code was to confirm/not-confirm my (natural) understanding of the use of a `template<typename>` template. As there is no parameter for the template type given, I'd thought that such a construct would help in overload resolution. That is, without the template annotations it is clear that I would get the above output. But with the template annotation I'd have thought that I maybe could force the compiler to take (in case of the `3-call`) the `char-variant` of the `printnum()` function, which isn't the case.

So my general question is: *What is the use of the `template<typename>` construct?*

Comment: The use is to define a template with a single template parameter: a class. That's what it is. Both "2" and "3" are `int`s, as such the function that takes the `int` parameter gets selected. The template parameter is not a factor.

Comment: There's certainly "use". There are many templates in the C++ library that take a single class as a parameter.

Comment: Well yes, but this doesn't answer the question

Comment: There is no point to it in this code *at all*. Since the template argument is not used *anywhere* (much less for overload resolution), it doesn't matter. You could put `printnum<double>(3)` in this and the `int` parameter overload is *still* the best choice from `printnum<double>(int)` and `printnum<double>(char)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well yes, that's clear, because the code didn't do what I "hoped" it to do and exercised the default overload resolution behavior,  the use of an "empty template" was useless. So maybe you could give an example where such an "empty template" makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is to allow for an argument to be explicitly specialized.  Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename> void printnum(int i);

template<>
void printnum<int>(int i) {
    std::cout<<"in int method: "<<i<<std::endl;
}

template<>
void printnum<char>(int i) {
    std::cout<<"in char method: "<<i<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    printnum<int>(2);
    printnum<char>(3);
}
```

This program prints:

```
in int method: 2
in char method: 3
```

It creates two different `printnum(int)` functions that are selected by the explicit template parameter.  The main use of this is when you want to call `printnum<T>(int)` from some other template function that has a `T` type parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have a family of functions, for all types `T`, taking `int` as a parameter (there's no connection between `T` and `int`); and incidentally, all doing the same thing. You have another family of functions, for all types `T`, taking a `char` as a parameter.

Omitting the name `T` doesn't convey any magical properties on your function templates: `template <typename T> void f();` and `template <typename> void f();` are exactly equivalent.

`printnum<int>(2)` instantiates one function from the first family (for `T == int`), and one function from the second family, and performs overload resolution on them. The function from the first family wins. Same with `printnum<char>(3)`

---

You might be thinking of template specialization:

```
template <typename T> void printnum(T);

template<>
void printnum(int i) {

    std::cout<<"in int method:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< i<<std::endl;
}

template<typename>
void printnum(char i) {

    std::cout<<"in char method:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<(int)i<<std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CQE93494)

Here, there's a single family of functions. Only two members of this family are actually defined (an attempt to use any other instantiation would result in a linker error). The template argument unambiguously selects a particular member of the family; since there's only one viable function to call, no overload resolution is performed.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good explanation. So the only effect in general is to create a family of functions of which at compile-time one is chosen, which is identical to all other functions of the family. But I can't see why this is making sense.

Comment: It generally doesn't. It's unclear why you would want to create a function template, and not use its template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
template<typename>
void printnum(int i) {
    std::cout<<"in int method:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< i<<std::endl;
}
```

is the same as

```
template<typename T>
void printnum(int i) {
    std::cout<<"in int method:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< i<<std::endl;
}
```

except that the parameter is unnamed. Since the parameter is not used in any way (you can't use it - it doesn't have a name), it doesn't influence anything.

The template parameter has no name. That's it. But the function remains a template so one needs to pass it a type parameter. The same way you can avoid naming the function parameter to avoid "unused parameter" warnings, you can do the same here.

(sometimes you need to have unused parameters in functions because a callback has a given signature and you must declare a parameter because the callback signature demands it, but it just happens you don't use it)

Comment: So, this construct is useless. Otherwise you could give an example, to why this construct isn't useless.

Comment: @FloriHe Avoiding to name a template parameter is as useful as avoiding naming the function parameter: avoiding "unused parameter" warnings.